# Increase the timestamp precision of an event to milliseconds (Google Analytics 4)

Tags: events, google-analytics, timestamp

I have a custom event created directly on the web page, as follows:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {'value': <value>});
```

Google Analytics 4 is recording them and I can see them in the reports.
My problem is that the timestamp of the events has a precision of 1 second and sometimes, when two events occur in a row within the same second, GA4 records them with the same timestamp, and sometimes interleaves them in the timeline, putting the first one after the second one and breaking the sequence order.
I think this could be solved by increasing the timestamp precision of the custom event to milliseconds.
How can I do that?
Regards and thanks.

NOTE: I don't use Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to mark the event as conversion; that way GA4 receives the events immediately after they are generated on the web and they are perfectly ordered.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to increase the timestamp precision in `gtag()`

GA4 internally works with microseconds precision as "event_timestamp" in [BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en) is in microseconds.

GA4 batches events. It may send multiple at once. In general it adds an additional parameter `engagement_time_msec` ("_et") to every event which is milliseconds since the last event.

This way the order is kept.

You probably are not able to see it in GA4's UI, but you will in BQ.

If order is important to you within GA4's UI, you could use a custom dimension (i.e. a custom event parameter) and increment it.

#### Example

Add

```
window.eventOrderCounter = 1;
```

before or after

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

and use

```
gtag('event', <action>, {'order': "#" + window.eventOrderCounter++, 'value': <value>});
```

add "order" as custom dimension for events in GA4's UI.

Comment: Hello.

Thank you very much.

Yes, keeping the order of events is very important. Each event is a chess move, for example:

event_1: “1. e4,”
event_2: “1. ..., e5;”
event_3: “2. Nf3,”
event_4: “2. ..., Nc6;”
event_5: “3. Bc4,”
event_6: “3. ..., Bc5;”
event_7: “4. c3,”
etc.

What I don't understand is that if GA4 works internally with millisecond precision why does it mess up the events in its user interface.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting because I stumbled upon this by accident and the solutions presented by @MA40 and @TimW are less than ideal.

What I would do is add a custom even parameter that holds a timestamp you generate. If you do not use GTM, your gtag code may look like this:

```js
gtag('event', 'yourEvent', {
 'param1': 'yourParamValue',
'custom_timestamp': new Date().getTime()
});
```

You can then [use BigQuery](https://www.teamsimmer.com/2023/01/12/how-do-i-access-the-individual-timestamp-of-a-ga4-event/) to get the proper sequence of events, based on your more accurate timestamp. If you can't use BigQuery, the UI won't be of much help unfortunately.